# creating an element using jquery fails in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am creating a label based on user input using JQuery. Following is the code snippet -

```
 $('#inputID').after('<label id="newLabel">Created</label>');
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, however breaks in IE.
I tried using insertAfter and append but results are same.
I used Developer Tools and pagesource to see if label has been generated or not, but couldn't see it. However, it is visible on the page.

Comment: IE dev tools does not show a Live Dom tree.

Comment: If it is visible then why do you say it is broken?  Just because IE's crappy tools don't show it in the DOM?

Comment: It's visible on the page. But whole css stuff is broken for it. Hence, I can test it without seeing it in a DOM tree

Comment: Try [firebug lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable)

Comment: I tested it in IE 7 8 and 9 and its working...

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) of what exactly is not working?

Comment: I got the root cause of my error...it was because of display:inline-block...and this doesn't work in IE, so I will look into changing that...

Answer (score 1):

IE 8 has some issues with Javascript. However try using a different jQuery version it might be useful...

Comment: I dont think you should have answered, there is no indication the OP is using version 8 and there is also no indication of JQuery version. For all you know, the OP may be using the latest version of both

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically generated elements are not visible in the pagesource, if you hit <kbd>ctrl+u</kbd> to see the page source you can't find that.

`Although that can be find with firebug or inspecting in chrome dev tools.`

In firefox if you are using webdeveloper extension that can let you see the `view generated source` which is in the view source tab in this extension bar.

Comment: This is not an answer and should have been posted as a comment

Comment: I used Chrome Dev tools and Firebug too and it's being rendered properly over there. Since it's the IE issue I have to see what's the output over there...

Comment: i have tested it in ie8 and dev tool of ie also rendering properly.